# Connecting Microstrategy Cube to a Postgres Materialized View

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views, microstrategy

I have created a Materialized View in a Postgres Database. When I am creating my microstrategy cube connection to this Postgres Database, I am unable to see this Materialized View.

Can anyone help me to understand why I am unable to see this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the read settings for your Warehouse Catalog.
Location: Schema->Warehouse Catalog Options->Catalog->Read Settings

Query for tables:

```
SELECT n.nspname as NAME_SPACE,
  c.relname as TAB_NAME
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relkind in ('v', 'm', 'r', 'p', '')
      AND n.nspname <> 'pg_catalog'
      AND n.nspname <> 'information_schema'
      AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Column Query:
hanged to LEFT JOIN in on table INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS (no issues for me so far)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    nspname                                      AS NAME_SPACE,
    relname                                      AS TAB_NAME,
    attname                                      AS COL_NAME,
    typname                                      AS DATA_TYPE,
    COALESCE(B.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, attlen) AS DATA_LEN,
    NUMERIC_PRECISION                            AS DATA_PREC,
    NUMERIC_SCALE                                AS DATA_SCALE
FROM
    pg_attribute A
JOIN
    pg_class C
ON
    A.attrelid = C.oid
JOIN
    pg_namespace N
ON
    C.relnamespace = N.oid
JOIN
    pg_type T
ON
    A.atttypid = T.oid
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS B
ON
    A.attname = B.COLUMN_NAME
AND C.relname = B.TABLE_NAME
AND N.nspname = B.TABLE_SCHEMA
WHERE
    relname IN (#TABLE_LIST#)
AND attnum > 0
ORDER BY
    1,
    2,
    3
```

Especially the columns query could be improved but until now I haven't looked back at this as it works fine.

Reason for all of this can be found in the following discussion: [Materialized views don't show up in information_schema](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3794.1412980686%40sss.pgh.pa.us).

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround for this...

You can create the view as a standard view, connect this to Microstrategy, and then delete the view and created as a Materialized View. This will then pick up the newly created Materialized view as long as you keep the same name.